# Divide a dimensionless number by a number with a unit

Tags: python, list, math, units-of-measurement, astropy

I have a list of dimensionless number in python and I am trying to divide it by a number with a unit (the unit is associated via astropy).

```
my_list = [34.567, 34.436, 34.764]
plate_scale_arc = 0.04*u.arcsec
plate_scale_deg = plate_scale_arc.to(u.deg) 

new_list = [(i/plate_scale_deg) for i in my_list]
```

How do I get this to actually do the arithmetic and not worry about the units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`value`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.units.quantity.Quantity.html#astropy.units.quantity.Quantity.value) attribute of `plate_scale_deg`.

```
>>> [(i/plate_scale_deg.value) for i in my_list]
[3111030.0, 3099240.0, 3128760.0]
```